# How to extract data from JSON object from JQuery getJSON

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display JSON data that looks like this:

```
{
    "response": {
        "@attributes": {
            "status": "ok",
            "version": "12"
        },
        "label": {
            "@attributes": {
                "plid": "1234",
                "name": "demo"
            }
        },
        "page": {
            "@attributes": {
                "name": "bookinfo"
            },
            "count": 1,
            "pages": "144",
            "current_page": 1,
            "isbn10": "0824828917",
            "isbn13": "9780824828912",
            "title": "Surf Science",
            "author": "Tony Butt - Paul Russell - Rick Grigg",
            "binding": "Paperback",
            "msrp": 34,
            "publisher": "University of Hawaii Press",
            "published_date": "2004-07-01",
            "edition": "2nd",
            "rank": 176243,
            "rating": 0,
            "_amazon_item": null,
            "image": "http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51-dKe7tztL._SL75_.jpg"
        }
    }
}​
```

I know the JQuery call .getJSON can be used to get an object like the one above, but I dont know how to extract data from it so I can dynamically display it on a webpage. Any ideas on how to do this with JQuery/Javascript? For instance How would I get the Author or title?

My code below (only difference is that when I test it I actually use my real key):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://api2.campusbooks.com/12/rest/search",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        key : "[my_key]",
        keywords : "calc",
        timeout : "7",
        format : "json"
      },
      success: function(jsonData) {
        console.log("Success! " + jsonData);
      },
      error: function(jsonData) {
        console.log("Error! " + jsonData);
      }
    });
      </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

What prints in the firebug console is:

```
 Error! [object Object]
```

so the object being returned is just [object Object]. The "Error! " part is just from my code. When I just put all the variables into 1 url and go to it then the page shows this:

```
{"response":{"@attributes":{"status":"ok","version":"12"},"label":{"@attributes":{"plid":"[1234]","name":"[my_name]"}},"page":{"@attributes":{"name":"search"},"count":1000,"pages":100,"current_page":1,"results":{"book":[{"isbn10":"0538497394","isbn13":"9780538497398","title":"Essential Calculus: Early Transcendentals, Enhanced Edition (with Enhanced WebAssign with eBook Printed Access Card for Multi Term Math and Science)","author":"James Stewart","binding":"Hardcover","msrp":177.95,"pages":"944","publisher":"Brooks Cole","published_date":"2010-01-01","edition":"1","rank":12133,"rating":0,"image":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/41%2Bk0odfWaL._SL75_.jpg"},{"isbn10":"1439058474","isbn13":"9781439058473","title":"Dosage Calculations (Available Titles 321 Calc!dosage Calculations Online)","author":"Gloria D. Pickar - Amy Pickar-Abernethy","binding":"Paperback","msrp":90.95,"pages":"720","publisher":"Delmar Cengage Learning","published_date":"2012-01-01","edition":"9","rank":2004,"rating":0,"image":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/41TcBjzhPnL._SL75_.jpg"},{"isbn10":"0840065639","isbn13":"9780840065636","title":"Applied CALC (with Mathematics CourseMate with eBook Printed Access Card)","author":"Frank Wilson","binding":"Paperback","msrp":83.95,"pages":"256","publisher":"Brooks Cole","published_date":"2011-01-01","edition":"1","rank":514542,"rating":0,"image":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/516p3a40S4L._SL75_.jpg"},{"isbn10":"1430231599","isbn13":"9781430231592","title":"Beginning OpenOffice Calc: From Setting Up Simple Spreadsheets to Business Forecasting","author":"Jacek Artymiak","binding":"Paperback","msrp":39.99,"pages":"136","publisher":"Apress","published_date":"2011-09-05","edition":"1","rank":682980,"rating":0,"image":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51FFF95bq4L._SL75_.jpg"},{"isbn10":"0071488456","isbn13":"9780071488457","title":"Bob Miller's High School Calc for the Clueless - Honors and AP Calculus AB & BC (Bob Miller's Clueless Series)","author":"Bob Miller","binding":"Paperback","msrp":12.95,"pages":"246","publisher":"McGraw-Hill","published_date":"2007-08-14","edition":"1","rank":1121409,"rating":0,"image":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51Adl-dr0cL._SL75_.jpg"},{"isbn10":"0821848178","isbn13":"9780821848173","title":"Riot at the Calc Exam and Other Mathematically Bent Stories","author":"Colin Adams","binding":"Paperback","msrp":32,"pages":"271","publisher":"American Mathematical Society","published_date":"2009-07-21","edition":"","rank":625803,"rating":0,"image":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51Jvoh2ZQtL._SL75_.jpg"},{"isbn10":"111816170X","isbn13":"9781118161708","title":"Calculus II For Dummies","author":"Mark Zegarelli","binding":"Paperback","msrp":19.99,"pages":"384","publisher":"For Dummies","published_date":"2012-01-24","edition":"2","rank":16179,"rating":0,"image":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51W8PJsg%2BZL._SL75_.jpg"},{"isbn10":"1847190979","isbn13":"9781847190970","title":"Learn OpenOffice.org Spreadsheet Macro Programming: OOoBasic and Calc automation: A fast and friendly tutorial to writing macros and spreadsheet applications","author":"Dr Mark Alexander Bain","binding":"Paperback","msrp":39.99,"pages":"220","publisher":"Packt Publishing","published_date":"2006-12-22","edition":"","rank":1118193,"rating":0,"image":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51SOipRUqOL._SL75_.jpg"},{"isbn10":"0495014281","isbn13":"9780495014287","title":"Essential Calculus: Early Transcendentals (Stewart's Calculus Series)","author":"James Stewart","binding":"Hardcover","msrp":190.95,"pages":"912","publisher":"Brooks Cole","published_date":"2006-03-01","edition":"1","rank":1392,"rating":0,"image":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/41T-md-t%2B6L._SL75_.jpg"},{"isbn10":"0764146939","isbn13":"9780764146930","title":"Barron's AP Calculus, 11th Edition","author":"David Bock  M.S. - Shirley O. Hockett  M.A.","binding":"Paperback","msrp":18.99,"pages":"696","publisher":"Barron's Educational Series","published_date":"2012-02-01","edition":"11","rank":3475,"rating":0,"image":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51GENtM0pGL._SL75_.jpg"}]}}}}
```

URL used:

```
http://api2.campusbooks.com/12/rest/search?key=[my_key]&keywords=calc&timeout=7&format=json
```

Comment: The MDN JavaScript Guide has a whole section about working with objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: When parsed, you have a structure of objects. Property access for an object is `object.property` or `object["property"]`... the latter giving more flexibility for non valid identifier characters, like `@`.

Comment: Additional resources: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the JSON is returned as you showed, here's an example:

```
$.getJSON("some/URL", function(jsonData) {
    $("#titleDiv").html(jsonData.response.page.title); 
    // #titleDiv now holds the text "Surf Science"

    // another way
    $("#authorDiv").html(jsonData["response"]["page"]["author"]);
    // #authorDiv now holds the text "Tony Butt - Paul Russell - Rick Grigg"
});
```

Perhaps a better way to do it is to use `$.ajax`, since that's what jQuery uses behind the scenes anyway.  This way you can specify both a success and an error handler function which will help with debugging any problems you may have:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://api2.campusbooks.com/12/rest/bookinfo",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    key : "[yourkey]",
    isbn : "0538497815",
    timeout : "6",
    format : "json"
  },
  success: function(jsonData) {
    console.log("Success! " + jsonData);
  },
  error: function(request, status, error) {
    console.log("Error! " + request.responseText);
  }
});
```

If an error occurs you should be able to find out what it is by looking in the browser's JavaScript console.
By the way, you can specify the parameters as I have done above rather than putting them into the URL.

There are also a number of developer tools available to help with this type of thing, such as the [REST Console app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn) for Google Chrome or the [RESTClient add-in](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/restclient/) for Firefox.  They make it easy to enter your request parameters and determine what may be causing issues.

Comment: I understand your code but it does not seem to work... would there be someway to check if I'm getting back any data at all?

Comment: Be sure you replace "some/URL" with the correct URL, and then put something like this in the callback function: "alert('JSON returned!');"  If you're getting back any data at all, you'll get a popup alert.  You could also add a "console.log(jsonData);" in the function to print out the JSON object to the browser's JavaScript console.  This would allow you to see the exact format of the JSON returned.

Comment: ok so that was the problem. It seems that no data has been returned. I am using a url from campusbooks.com and their "API is implemented via an HTTP GET request in a standard REST format". The url I use looks like http://api2.campusbooks.com/12/rest/bookinfo?key=[mykey]&isbn=0538497815&timeout=6&format=json with [mykey] replaced with my actual key. Does it look like I did something wrong?

Comment: I updated my answer with additional advice; hopefully this helps.

Comment: When I used the REST Client add-in for Firefox and I got no error and I get all the data I need using the url http://api2.campusbooks.com/12/rest/bookinfo?key=[my_key]&isbn=0538497815&timeout=6&format=json but I get an error when I use it with JQuery. It just returns [Object Object] in JQuery.

Comment: An Object is what you should get back.  Perhaps you just aren't seeing the data that is inside it.  Is the `success()` or `error()` function getting called back?  Try accessing some property of the object and see what happens (for example, `jsonData.response.page.title`).

Comment: I added more info to my question so that should better explain what's going on.

Comment: Try changing your error handler to what I have above.  Now a description of the error should be printed to the console